# I can't understand why my quesiton was closed

Tags: discussion, policy, close-reasons

I can't understand why my question was closed:
[Rotate An Integer Array with an O(n) algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17415/rotate-an-integer-array-with-an-on-algorithm)

It was previously put "on hold", then I edited my question to meet the requirements.
But then it was closed.

I can't understand what is wrong with this question.

Comment: "On-hold" and "closed" are the same state in the system, it is just given the former name at first to emphasize that this is a reversible state. Your question is now accumulating re-open votes. That said, I would (personally, no moderator hat) describe this as a really uninteresting challenge.

Answer (score 1):

"On-hold" and "closed" are the same thing in Stack Exchange.

Also, since your question has been edited to meet the requirements it was placed in the review queue until it gained 5 reopen votes upon which it was taken off hold/reopened.